# Python Numba: how to slice a column from a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I understand that Numba supports a number of NumPy functions in nopython mode: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

However, is there a way to slice a column or a row from a NumPy array in nopython mode?

Something like

```
x= y[:,mycol]
x=y[myrow,:]
```

doesn't work in nopython mode. The only workaround I found is to slice the array outside Numba, and pass the 'slices' to my Numba function, but this is not always feasible or straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

What version of Numba are you using? With 0.26.0, the following works:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def func(x, mycol):
    y = x[:,mycol]

    return y

x = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
mycol = 2
y = func(x, mycol)

print np.allclose(x[:,mycol], y)  # True
```

Comment: I'm using 0.20.0 . I don't want to upgrade now as I cannot run the risk of finding some incompatibility with the previous versions, as was the case in the past. I'll upgrade as soon as I have some time. Thanks!

Comment: PS I assume you don't know of a way to do this with version 0.20, right?

Comment: I just tested the same code with 0.20 and it works on my machine